# My mouse pointer seems to lag visually, leaving cursor 'foot prints'

Tags: mouse, graphics

These 'footprints' seem to disappear after some time but it happens regularly. Any idea what i should look into?

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)

sudo lshw -C display                          
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108M [GeForce GT 635M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:a0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:e1000000-e107ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:e1400000-e17fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:6000(size=64)
```

Comment: Start by adding your graphical hardware to your question via an edit.

Comment: How do I do that, get that information?

Comment: Either from the make/model of your PC, or by following the instructions here http://askubuntu.com/questions/12780/how-to-find-out-what-graphics-card-is-present-in-your-system

Comment: Did you try installing the previous driver version ?